# How to set custom colors on jqplot mekko chart?

Tags: colors, jqplot

Is there any way to set specific background colors for the mekko chart in jqplot?

Examples on the jqplot website always show the same set of colors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that particular chart in jqPlot, but this usually works for assigning colours:

```
series: [ 
    { color: "#aaff11" }, // series 1 color
    { color: "#991166" }, // series 2 color
    { color: "#33ff66" }  // series 3 color (and so on)
]
```

where `series` above is a key in the `options` object passed to `$.jqplot(id, data, options)`.

See [the docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/optionsTutorial-txt.html) for more info.